# Is it possible to dynamically change the number of decimal places in appsheet's same column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-appsheet

In the google app_sheet(*these formulas similar to the excel formulas, therefore if you know the solution with the excel, please let me know*) I need to set a the column for dynamically change decimal places.

as a example when a calculated value comes to '45.20', it must be '45.2', but when a value comes with '45.11', it must stay as the same.

This is important for some calculations, therefore can't put the column type as text or something like that.

does anyone know a solution to this appreciation for let me know!

thank you.

Comment: If there is an Excel solution, why do you think it relevant to Google app_sheet?

Answer (score 1):

From my tests it would appear that Format->Number->Automatic does what you want.
[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I want. how did you do that ? could you explain with more details?

Comment: Nira, I don't know what you mean by more detail? You simply format the cells as indicated in the answer. What portion don't you understand?